# Distributing an app for all company iPads

Tags: ipad, ios-appstore

If I build an iPad app for a company (for internal use), do I need to commit it to the App Store to install it on all company devices ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the following links from [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/):

- [iOS installing apps without app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848916/ios-installing-apps-without-app-store/3848932)
- [iPhone app without AppStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982476/iphone-app-without-appstore)
- [Private iPhone App, without App Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583920/private-iphone-app-without-app-store)

Comment: @timbooo ok, thanks for the links. By the way, since it is 300 euros per year, maybe it is better to submit it to the app store and then download it for free... could you give me some info about it ?

Comment: In order to submit an app to the app store you have to have at least a 99 dollars/year Developer subscription.

Comment: @Patrick - well I think your company should decide on how to deploy your to your clients. I don't think it's that benefiting to use the App Store if the app does some internal stuff.

Comment: @timbooo And what about syncing the iPads with an iTunes account built for the company ? Is there a limit to the number of iPads synced with iTunes (just to have the same app on all iPads) ? If this is not possible, I think still it is more convenient to pay 99$ rather than 300$ per year, and share the app in this way, as long as there are not privacy issues.

Comment: @Patrick - according to [this](http://chimac.net/2010/05/24/does-itunes-have-a-device-limit/) and [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2439080?threadID=2439080&tstart=15) itunes does not have a device limit. So if you want to sync x iPads with 1 account you should be good to go. And if it shouldn't work, there are still the other options ;)

Comment: @timbooo So, does it work 100% ? Can anybody confirm this ? Just because I need to provide professional help to a company and it would be bad if this is not true

Comment: By the way, isn't this strange ? Group of friends could buy songs and apps with the same iTunes account...

Comment: I can't tell if it works 100% - I've never done it personally. Sorry.

Comment: @timbooo ok, one last question, just to be sure. If I want to install the app on my own iPad, do I need to submit it to the appStore, or can I just install it without paying any developer fees ?

Comment: @Patrick - Since this is too specific for me try these links: [Deploying iPone Apps to Real iPhone] (http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/deploying-iphone-apps-real-devices) [Stack Overflow Search] (http://www.google.de/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=how+to+deploy+company+iphone+app+to+clients#sclient=psy&hl=de&source=hp&q=site:stackoverflow.com+how+to+deploy+company+iphone+app+to+clients&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=29ba8719137c5168)